# Newton's method for nonlinear equations system

Tags: functions, numerics

My code is:

```
Newton[F_, X0_, \[Epsilon]_] := Module[{M, M0},
M = Table[
D[F[[i]], Subscript[x, j]] /. {Subscript[x, 1] -> X0[[1]], 
 Subscript[x, 2] -> X0[[2]]}, {i, 1, Length[F]}, {j, 1, 
Length[F]}];
F = {\!\(
\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(x\), \(1\), \(2\)] + 
\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(x\), \(2\), \(2\)]\), 
Subscript[x, 1] + 2 Subscript[x, 1] Subscript[x, 2]};
X0={2,2};
\[Epsilon] = 0.1;
Newton[F,X0,\[Epsilon]]
```

How can I make those x_1->X0[[1]] and x_2->X0[[2]] "automatized"?
I mean, if the X0 and F will be very big, I think it would be very bad idea to write it one after another.

Thanks in advance

Pink Floyd fan

Comment: It's better (of readibility _and_ for performance) to use arrays for the internal calculations instead of `Subscript`. Moreover, your code has several syntax issues and seems uncomplete...

Comment: About the "automization" part: Maybe this is what you look for: `Thread[Thread[Subscript[x, Range[Length[X0]]]] -> X0]`

Comment: Thanks,that's it! My code was incomplete because i couldn't move on without that part.